# reduce response time from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

My WCF service is returning around 7MB data in string format to client.

Client has to wait for the response.

What appropriate bindings that need to modified in config file or any other method which will reduce the response time from WCF Service?

```
 public string GetData() //Without compression
    {
        return File.ReadAllText("SampleDB");
    }


    private string GetDataforCompression() //with compression
    {
       string data=File.ReadAllText("SampleDB");
       Compress(data);

    }

    public static string Compress(string ToCompress)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ToCompress);

        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gs = new DeflateStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {

                CopyTo(msi, gs);
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(mso.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static void CopyTo(Stream src, Stream dest)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

        int cnt;

        while ((cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt);
        }
    }
```

I tried sending the data in compressed form and decompressing at the client end but there was'nt significant variation in response time.Below is client side config file

```
 <customBinding>
        <binding name="httpbinarybinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="65536000" maxArrayLength="4194304" maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000"  maxBufferSize="65536000" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Comment: Are you using streaming?

Comment: I have just set transfer mode to streamed in the config file.But there is no much difference in the response time

Comment: If you don't want cross machine communication, you can try netNamedPipeBinding. if you can post some demo code and your observation regarding response time, it would be much clear.

Comment: I do require cross m/c communication inn my application.               I've put sampleconfig file used and the method GetData() which returns 7MB data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a lot of data to send down the line at one time can you not build in paging in your method / web application? Also maybe have a look at iis compression gzip.

Comment: Thanks Laird Streak..I will have a look into paging

Answer (score 0):

I could not find where you have mentioned 'transferMode' in your Custom Binding

```
<binding name="TransferService"
   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
   maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >
```

Streaming will help you to pass your data in chunks. 
This will help to you manage user response or at least will help in showing progress bar.

Please check following links for details:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx

Sometimes, knowing datalength may be required for processing data @client side.
You may expose it using message contract.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/472a7b38-f4fe-420e-85be-ae9c744a94a7

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal. I basically had tried                      `<httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" transfermode="Streamed"  maxBufferSize="65536000" /> `            which didnt reduce the response time.Wii have a look into the links specified

Comment: Post your conclusion to benefit others

Comment: Chunking Channel Method helps ..Thanks Ujjwal